# argo workflow continue to build new images even though the build has succeeded but I want to delete the workflow when succeeded

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo-workflows, argo, kpack

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: argo-service-sensor
  namespace: argo-events
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: test-dep
      eventSourceName: deploy-service-event
      eventName: example
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: webhook-workflow-trigger
        k8s:
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          resource: workflows
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: service-workflow-
              spec:
                serviceAccountName: ecr-service-account
                entrypoint: serviceWorkflow
                templates:
                  - name: serviceWorkflow
                    resource:
                      successCondition: status.phase == Succeeded
                      failureCondition: status.phase in (Failed, Error)
                      action: create
                      manifest: |
                        apiVersion: kpack.io/v1alpha2
                        kind: Image
                        metadata:
                          generateName: kpack-image-
                          namespace: kpack
                        spec:
                          tag: xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/demo-app:latest
                          serviceAccountName: ecr-service-account
                          namespace: kpack
                          builder:
                            name: kpack-builder
                            kind: ClusterBuilder
                            namespace: kpack
                          source:
                            git:
                              url: https://github.com/name/nodejs.git
                              revision: main
```

I want to delete the workflow when the pod has succeed but the workflow does not stop

I have already added the condition but even when it succeed the workflow  does not stop. It keeps building new kpack-images

The logs is on the picture attached to this post.

How do I go about it?

Error

```
time="2023-09-07T12:51:29 UTC" level=info msg="0/1 success conditions matched"
time="2023-09-07T12:51:29 UTC" level=info msg="Waiting for resource image.kpack.io/kpack-image-7c7zb in namespace kpack resulted in
retryable error: Neither success condition nor the failure condition has been matched. Retrying..."
time="2023-09-07T12:51:34 UTC" level=info msg="failure condition '{status.phase == [F]}' evaluated false"
time="2023-09-07T12:51:34 UTC" level=info msg="success condition '{status.phase == [Succeeded]}' evaluated false"
time="2023-09-07T12:51:34 UTC" level=info msg="0/1 success conditions matched"
time="2023-09-07T12:51:34 UTC" level=info msg="Waiting for resource image.kpack.io/kpack-image-7c7zb in namespace kpack resulted in
retryable error: Neither success condition nor the failure condition has been matched. Retrying..."
```